# Why cant we use std::find with std::map

Tags: c++, stl

I am aware that `std::map` has its own find method. But I wanted to know why we cant use `std::find`. I tried this

```
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string,std::string> mp;
    mp["hello"] = "bye";
    if(std::find(mp.begin(),mp.end(),"hello")!=mp.end()))
    {
        std::cout << "found" ;
    }

}
```

and I get the exception

```
no matching function for call to 'find(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator, const char [6])'
     if(std::find(mp.begin(),mp.end(),"hello")!=mp.end()))
```

Comment: I wish someone would also mention why a question is being down voted too

Comment: There are a lot of haters on SO, unfortunately. I think this is a reasonable question to ask.

Comment: *" I get the **exception**"*: Wrong wording, you got a compilation error.

Comment: @MistyD: We are actually encouraged by the SE managers _not_ to explain downvotes, as it leads to fights. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285081/560648 (and feel free to weep)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can, but we have to pass the appropriate argument. The "value type" of a map is a pair consisting of the key (in `const` form) and the value. As such, you'd have to pass the entire pair of key and value in order to use `std::find`:

```
std::find(mp.begin(),mp.end(),std::make_pair("hello","hello"))
```

*(or something like that)*

Of course, in the specialised case of an associative container, that is silly: we usually only want to search on key. Hence the special `std::map::find` exists.

Also, a specialised searching tool that "knows about" a map's internal tree-like structure is far more efficient (think binary search!) than a version that just takes iterators to "some data that can be iterated", and thus must traverse the data linearly, in value order. That's why you want to use `std::set::find`, even though a set element's key *is* its value.